# Validar el input con la regex solo si contiene una unica palabra delante de un patron de opcion

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, validación

Necesito que si se tiene un input como

`PC es bueno y rapido`

entre a la regex y extrae `"PC"` , `"bueno y rapido"`

Pero si ya hubiese mas de una palabra delante de la parte de opcion `()` entonces, que no valide la condicion de la regex. Por ejemplo:
`Creo que ese PC antiguo es bueno y rapido`

En ese caso no deberia entrar a la regex porque `Creo que ese PC antiguo`  es mas de una palabra

Aqui mi code, crei que deberia funcionar por el `\s*?` sin emabargo esta validando todo sea o no una sola palabra.

En el patron se busca que incluya una palabra (en numeros o letras), pero solamente una.

```py
import re

input_text = input()

#regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:fueron |fue |serian |seria |es |son )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??" #primer patron que puede contener varias palabras (no sirve)
regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+\s*?)+?)? \s*\¿?(?:fueron |fue |serian |seria |es |son )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??" #primer patron que puede contener una palabra


m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

if m1:
    word, association = m1.groups()

    word = word.strip()
    association = association.strip()

    print(repr(word))
    print(repr(association))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión que buscas es:

```
(\S+)\s+(fueron |fue |serian |seria |es |son )(.*)
```

que se lee así:

1. Comienza con una palabra (\S+),
2. separada por uno o más espacios \s+,
3. seguido de una palabra como "fueron ", "fue ",
4. seguido cualquier cosa (.*)

y usamos `match`, que por definición calza desde el comienzo del texto.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(\S+)\s+(fueron |fue |serian |seria |es |son )(.*)")

tests = [
    "PC es grande y rápido",
    "El PC fue de mi papá",
    "La casa que fue de mi abuelo",
    "Prince fue "
]

for test in tests:
    print(f"Test {test}: ", end="")
    m1 = patron.match(test)

    if m1:
        word, association, resto = m1.groups()

        word = word.strip()
        association = association.strip()

        print(f"Word {word},  Assoc: {association}, Resto: {resto}")
    else:
        print("falló")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la explicacion, lo probe en mi programa y me funciono!